# why does my prgram show runtime error in codechef ide when it doesn't in visual studio?

Tags: python

Given an array `A` of size `N` and an integer `K`, check if there exist any pair of index `i`, `j` such that `A[i] + A[j] = K` and `i ≠ j`. The first line should contain number of test cases, the second line should contain input `N` and `K`. I coded but it's showing runtime error. How can I fix that? Code is given below.

I have already run the program in visual studio and it's working fine but when i submitted to codechef it shows runtime error.

```py
#following is my code where T is number of test cases
T = int(input())

while T != 0:
    #size of array and value of K ,also the array
    N, K = map(int, input().split())
    A = list(map(int, input().split()))     
    l = 0
    r = N - 1
    flag = 0
    while l < r:
        if (A[l] + A[r] == K):
            flag = 1
            break
        elif (A[l] + A[r] < K):
            l += 1
            continue
        else:
            r -= 1 
            continue

    if flag == 1:
        print("Yes", end="\n")
    else:
        print ("No", end="\n")
```

The code should print `Yes` or no depending whether sum `K` is present in the array or not.

Comment: Can you show what error messages and any other output you are getting, in the question?

Comment: Has each testcase own `A`, `N` and `K`?
Could you please share the problem link?

Comment: Is input array sorted?

Comment: @mrzrm https://www.codechef.com/problems/CSUM here is the link to the question

Comment: @joanis I don't think we can post screenshots here but it's showing RE(NZEC) (0.02000)

Comment: You can copy and paste the output into the question, formatting it into a block quote so it looks like what you see. I don't understand what `RE(NZEC) (0.02000)` could mean, though, but maybe someone else will.

Comment: @joanis Sub-Task Task # Result
(time)
1 0 RE (NZEC)
(0.020000)
Subtask Score: 0.00% Result - RE
2 1 RE (NZEC)
(0.380000)
2 2 RE (NZEC)
(0.380000)
Subtask Score: 0.00% Result - RE  here is as it was showing in the output table,and about the subtasks I have provided a link to the question in the comments

Comment: I am sorry if I am still not clearing things out ,this is my first time in stack overflow and I am a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first your algorithm works only when the input array is sorted. In addition in your solution `T` is never changed, so `T != 0` condition is always true and cause infinity loop!

Here's my accepted solution for this [Problem](https://codechef.com/problems/CSUM). Let's check it!

```py
t = int(input())

for _ in range(t):
    n, k = map(int, input().split())
    arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

    found = False
    for i, a in enumerate(arr):
        for j, b in enumerate(arr):
            if i != j and a + b == k:
                found = True

    print('Yes' if found else 'No')
```

On [CodeChef](https://www.codechef.com/) IDE, when I tried *Run*, cause *Runtime Error*.

[image]

But when I tried *Run* with *Custom Input*, it worked. So I've decided to *Submit* my code and it accepted! Thus I think something wrong with [CodeChef](https://www.codechef.com/) IDE and suggest you to just submit your code.

Comment: aah I get it now,thank you so much. Definitely I learnt a lot. God bless you! ^_^